# iOS - Change vertical spacing between 2 UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I have 3 different scenarios for a single XIB File.

Here is the XIB File, I have 3 different UIView.

[image]

My scenarios are :

- View 2 is displayed and View 1 and View 3 are hidden.
- View 1 and View 3 are displayed and View 2 is hidden.
- View 1, View 2 and View 3 are displayed.

My question is concerning the second case, where only View 1 and View 3 are displayed.

I can hide View 2, but I would like for this specific case to make View 1 and View 3 closer.

[image]

How can I do it ?

I tried with something like this but without success.

```
-(void)setConstraints {

    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_infoView1
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:_infoView3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Step 1 : Connect top constraint of view 2 with view 1 similarly connect top constraint of view 3 with view 2 then create and map height constraints for view 1 view 2 and view 3.

Step 2 : For scenarios mentioned in question, put conditions for your cases and do steps mentioned below

1) View 2 is displayed and View 1 and View 3 are hidden.
set height constraint for view 1 and view 3 to zero 
heightConstraintOfView1.constant = 0
heightConstraintOfView3.constant = 0

2) View 1 and View 3 are displayed and View 2 is hidden.
set height constraint for view 2 to zero 
heightConstraintOfView2.constant = 0

3) View 1, View 2 and View 3 are displayed.
Don’t set height constraint for any view to zero.
```

I assume all other constraints are set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Set constraints from storyBoard :-

1: View 2 set the center(Horizontal and vertical) , leading and trailing (zero) and height set according multiplier the height of Xib.

2: View 1 set Equal leading , trailing and height of View 2 and bottom space from View 2 is zero.

3: View 3 set Equal leading , trailing and height of View 2 and top space from View 2 is zero.

```
•   View 2 is displayed and View 1 and View 3 are hidden.

     View2.isHidden = false
     View1.isHidden = true
     View3.isHidden = true
```

•  View 1 and View 3 are displayed and View 2 is hidden.

```
     View2.isHidden = true
     View1.isHidden = false
     View3.isHidden = false
```

•   View 1, View 2 and View 3 are displayed.

```
      View2.isHidden = false
      View1.isHidden = false
      View3.isHidden = false
```

And set color According as required.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to fill the parent view with the non-hidden views keeping the parent view height same as before ??

Answer (score 0):

Assign the height constraints for view1, view2 and view3.
Create the outlets for these constraints - heightConstraintView1, heightConstraintView2 and heightConstraintView3.

For the case, you want to hide the view2,set the height constraint for view2 as the height you want.

```
heightConstraintView2.constant = 5
```

In other case, set the height constraint as equal value for all views.

```
heightConstraint1.constant = heightConstraint2.constant = heightConstraint3.constant = <A constant value>
```